# AWS EC2 Target groups healthchecks price

Tags: amazon-web-services, healthcheck

I notice AWS Application Load Balancer sends every 300 seconds(max) health check to the servers(target groups, ec2 instance).
Does these health checks are included in free tier? couldn't find the answer anywhere. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html

Is there a way to cancel it?

Answer (score 1):

It's free

> Data transferred "in" to and "out" from Amazon Classic and Application Elastic Load Balancers using private IP addresses, between EC2 instances and the load balancer in the same AWS VPC is free.

**References**

[EC2 On Demand Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/)